# How does AMD (specifically RequireJs) handle dependancies across multiple modules

Tags: requirejs, js-amd

I have my main initialization script which calls require() and one of the dependencies is a utilities framework, but some of the other modules that I'm specifying via require() also themselves have defined this framework as a dependency.

For example (init.js):

```
require(['module-a', 'module-b', 'module-c'], function(a, b, c){
    // where module-c is the framework
});
```

And then in 'module-a' I have:

```
define(['module-c'], function(c){
    // utilize module-c framework
});
```

So how does AMD/RequireJs handle this scenario, does it load the same framework twice?

Any help appreciated.

Kind regards,
Mark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will only be loaded once, both of the above modules will get the same module value for 'module-c'.

Comment: Many thanks for confirming! That's exactly what I was hoping would happen because in my mind specifying the dependancy within each module made more sense as it meant I'd be able to take that module and re-use it elsewhere in a completely different another project.

Comment: Internally, the AMD loader keeps track of (i.e. caches) all modules.  When the modules are optimized/concatenated together, this is not interesting.  However, if any of the modules are loaded just-in-time, it's important to note that the AMD loader keeps track of _requests_ so that two near-simultaneous requests don't attempt to download the same module more than once.

Answer (score 2):

Incase its useful to others - Here's a situation I came across where a module was loaded twice:

For the following project structure:

```
~/prj/js/app/fileA.js
~/prj/js/app/util/fileB.js
~/prj/js/ext/publisher.js
```

where the RequireJs `baseurl` is `~/prj/js/app`

`fileA.js` refers to the external (ext) dependancy `publisher.js` as:

```
//fileA:
define(['../ext/publisher'], function(){});
```

But `fileB.js` refers to the same dependancy with a different path:

```
//fileB:
define(['../../ext/publisher'], function(){});
```

In short, for both files, the dependency paths are different although the dependancy is in the same location.  In this case, publisher.js gets loaded twice.

Use Firebug's `Net` tab to see it loading twice:

[image: dependency.js being loaded twice (firebug)]

This is easily fixed using `paths` to configure the external folder path (as explained in the [require_js docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles)):

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {ext: '../ext'}
});
```

After setting `paths`, the dependency is loaded just once with `fileA.js` and `fileB.js` both using the same dependency path as follows:

```
//fileA:
define(['ext/publisher'], function(){});
```

and

```
//fileB:
define(['ext/publisher'], function(){});
```